# How to enable lazy loading of listview items while scrolling up as well as scrolling down the listview in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, commonsware-cwac, cwac-endless

How to use cwac's endlessadapter library to enable lazy loading of listview items while scrolling up as well as scrolling down the listview in Android?

I have previously used the endlessadapter library to enable lazy loading while scrolling down but am confused as to how the same library can be used for bidirectional lazy loading.

Is there any other library which can do the same ? 
Is a custom class extending OnScrollListener the only way to implement this ?

Comment: As is noted on the project home page, the `cwac-endless` project is discontinued.